# Error URL connection. (app android to server java)

Tags: android, rest

I'm trying to connect an Android application to a tomcat server in localhost.

I've hotspotted my mobile device and connected my pc on wifi mobile network, for having pc and mobile phone connected by the same network.
But when I try to connect my mobile phone to server, I've a I/O Exeption in application side. So application can't connect to server.

Application size

```
public void send(){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
String http = "http://192.168.152.19:8080/W7TurismoServer/Servlet";  
ArrayList<String> mostraArray=show();
HttpURLConnection urlConnection=null;  
try {  
    URL url = new URL(http);  
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);   
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");  
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);  
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);  
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");   
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host","http://192.168.152.19:8080/W7TurismoServer/Servlet");
    urlConnection.connect();  
    //Create JSONObject here*/
    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray arraypref=new JSONArray();

    arraypref.put(mostraArray);
    jsonParam.put("stringList",arraypref);
    System.out.println(jsonParam);
    OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(jsonParam.toString());
    out.close();  

    int HttpResult =urlConnection.getResponseCode();  
    if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
            urlConnection.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));  
        String line = null;  
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
            sb.append(line + "\n");  
        }  
        br.close();  

        System.out.println(""+sb.toString());  

    }else{  
            System.out.println(urlConnection.getResponseMessage());  
    }  
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {  

         e.printStackTrace();  
}  
catch (IOException e) {  

    e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{  
    if(urlConnection!=null)  
    urlConnection.disconnect();  
} }
```

Server size on post:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
      StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
      String line = null;
      try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
          jb.append(line);
      } catch (Exception e) { /*report an error*/ }

      try {

        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(jb.toString());
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        // crash and burn
        throw new IOException("Error parsing JSON request string");
      }}}
```

Comment: do you add a permission in manifest?

Comment: yes 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>`

Comment: What the error you have?

Comment: there lifts I/O Exeption

Comment: I understand. But i need a more detail explanation . Can you add a log to your post?